# after clicking the button submit,it call API ,the problem it is fired 2 times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
class User extends Component {

handleSubmit = (e, firstName, lastName) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault()
    const start = Date.now()
    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/user', {
        params: {
           firstName,
          lastName
        }
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

}
 render(){
   return (
      <Button  onClick={(e) =>    this.handleSubmit(e,firstname,lastname)}>submit</Button>
     )}
  }
```

I create API using nodejs ,named `/user` ,it is post method .

I try to consume it using reactjs,when press to the button submit and inspect to see what is going on in network ,It call 2 times,how do to fix this behavior ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUd0Z.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please provide a producible example: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can check that it really called twice and not a local mistake

Comment: Maybe the first request is an options request. I cannot see anywhere in the code you posted that would cause the click handler to be called twice unless button is pressed twice.

Comment: @user7836115 Why are commenting to yerself?

Comment: Why do you need `e.stopPropagation(); & e.preventDefault()` ? It's just a button with text `Submit`, not really a Submit button.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class User extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (e, firstName, lastName) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const start = Date.now();
    console.log(start);
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:4000/api/user", {
        params: {
          firstName,
          lastName
        }
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={e => this.handleSubmit(e, "hello", "world")}>
        submit
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default User;
```

forget to import axios. and its working fine

Comment: thx for your response ,axios is imported just i forget it to add here ,as  I said the problem is when i press to the button it is called or fired 2 times two 2 times

Comment: Its not firing two times once click the button it triggered handleSubmit only once.

Comment: you can see this picture how it called twice https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUd0Z.png

Answer (score 0):

have a nice day, i think u can try this:

```
   class User extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            sendingData:false
        }
        this.toggleSendingData= this.toggleSendingData.bind(this);
    }
    toggleSendingData(){
        this.setState({sendingData: !this.state.sendingData})
    }
  handleSubmit = (e, firstName, lastName) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    const start = Date.now();
    if(this.state.sendingData) return;
    this.toggleSendingData()
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:4000/api/user", {
        params: {
          firstName,
          lastName,
        },
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        this.toggleSendingData()
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        this.toggleSendingData()
      });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Button onClick={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e, firstname, lastname)}>
        submit
      </Button>
    );
  }
}
```

maybe you want to show a loader while u send the data, so the state to control that loader and if the user can send the request is a good approach, i hope help you